# Drawing a polyline in Java

Tags: java, graphics, polyline

I'm doing a task in my programmer course, and need to draw polyLines. I'm using Eclipse and I get no syntax errors with this code. But I don't understand why my polyLine isn't showing when I run the program. Anyone want to enlighten a fresh programmer? :)

Heres the code:

```
package oppgave4;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class CoordinateSystem extends JPanel {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int[] xSin = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        int[] ySin = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

        g.drawPolyline(xSin, ySin, xSin.length);
        g.drawLine(150, 0, 150, 300);
        g.drawLine(0, 150, 300, 150);
    }   
}
```

and the Test Program:

```
package oppgave4;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestProgram extends JFrame{
    public TestProgram(){
        add(new CoordinateSystem());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestProgram grid = new TestProgram();
        grid.setSize(300, 300);
        grid.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        grid.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Before drawing, does setting a color on the graphics context help? (Example: `g.setColor(Color.RED);`)

Comment: The polyline you draw would be very tiny and crumpled up in the upper left corner. Sure it is not there? Is the other line visible?

Comment: By adding color i could finally see the Line:) apparently it was so small and up in a corner that i did not see it. Thanks!

Comment: I added my suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before doing any drawing, you usually have to set an appropriate color in the graphics context. Otherwise it may be set to some random value from the previous user of the graphics context, or a default value like the background color.

In the example above, adding the following will make the graphics visible:

```
g.setColor(Color.RED);
```